# Is Oak for Deno primarily intended for static routing? Or can it handle dynamic routing (straightforwardly) too?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, url-routing, deno, oak

I am currently learning `Oak` for `Deno`.

I have grasped how to declare a static route to an API endpoint:

```
import helloWorld from './hello-world.ts';

// [... MORE CODE ...]

router.get('/hello-world', ({ response }: { response: any }) => {
    response.status = 200;
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.body = helloWorld;
});
```

But how would I go about dynamically routing, for example, requests to:

- `/hello-world-1`
- `/hello-world-2`
- `/welcome-page-1`
- `/welcome-page-2`

to:

- `./hello-world/1/page.ts`
- `./hello-world/2/page.ts`
- `./welcome-page/1/page.ts`
- `./welcome-page/2/page.ts`

assuming that both `hello-world` and `welcome-page` pagesets will continue until:

- `/hello-world-n`
- `/welcome-page-n`

I'm guessing I shouldn't need to manually route every request to every page in `server.ts`?

---

### Example:

I'm entirely happy to write the first parameter of `router.get()` as a **Regular Expression Wildcard** (and then, inside the method, grab the actual value using `arguments[0]`).

But, as far as I can tell, the method fails if that parameter is anything other than **a string**.

Answer (score 2):

[disclaimer: this is cobbled together without testing, maybe I got the escaping or other things wrong, feel free to correct me in comments]

Typically you route to individual pages in REST fashion with encoded parameters, like in the [basic usage](https://github.com/oakserver/oak#basic-usage) example. Relevant mini-snippit:

```
router.get("/path/:id", (context) => {}
```

which gives you a param `id` to look up individual pages in the function body.

As mentioned in the docs you can massage the path with the built-in [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters) module, like this:

```
router.get("/:path-:id(\\d+)", (context) => {}
```

which should give you the relevant parts the the params `path` (e.g. `hello-world` and `welcome-page`) and `id` (`1`, `2`, ...) to create the actual path on the filesystem (e.g. `./hello-world/1/page.ts`) or otherwise lookup the page data to return.